# Does tf.keras.utils.to_categorical remain consistent across multiple inputs?

Tags: python, keras

If I run `to_categorical` multiple times on different data with the same flags, but in different orders and counts, will I always get the same map from value to column? looking at the documentation [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/utils/to_categorical), I didn't see anything regarding consistancy.

Running a few tests, it *seems* like it respects ascending order:

```
to_categorical([0,1,2,3,4])
array([[1., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 1., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 1., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 1., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 1.]], dtype=float32)
```

where as in this example, 1 and 0 are reversed, which is what I would also expect

```
to_categorical([1,0,2,3,4])
array([[0., 1., 0., 0., 0.],
       [1., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 1., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 1., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 1.]], dtype=float32)
```

Is there any guarantee that this will be the case with all inputs?

Comment: For me the second matrix is right too. In the second element of the sequence (0) the one-hot encoding makes the  `[1, 0, 0, 0, 0]`. What you think is wrong?

Comment: @igorkf this is what I would expect, I'm wondering if this is a guarantee or a happy accident.